# Удаление данных без возможности восстановления в Linux

Tags: linux, безопасность, ext4

Вопрос такой: файловые системы линукс ext4 или btrfs используют журналирование, если программа стирает данные с диска (напр. shred) то что происходит с журналом - остаются там данные или их тоже надо как-то удалять ?

Comment: Для `ext4` по умолчанию журналируются только метаданные.
Там `shred` условно достаточно для безопасного удаления... У `btrfs` проблема скорее не в журнале, а в активном использовании *cow*'а и достаточно умного механизма выделения блоков... ИМХО там нет практически ни каких гарантий, что данные перезапишутся именно по тому месту, где они были или перезапишутся все копии блоков...

Comment: И как с этим бороться?

Comment: Если задача состоит в удалении всех данных в разделе, то проще записать случайную информацию сразу в раздел, минуя файловую систему. 
Как вариант, создать с помощью dd файл заполняющий все свободное место (что бы гарантировано переписались недавно удаленные блоки), а потом уже shred'ом пройтись по этому файлу.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdaX bs=1M`

Comment: С этим все ясно. Но что делать с возможными следами этой информации в журнале ФС ?

Comment: не использовать эту фс, очевидно же.

Comment: В моем случае не вариант .

Comment: нуда... для масла только термоядерные методы хоть как-то условно надёжны: от затирания всего свободного места (не забудь удалить файл из всех снепшотов сначала) до затирания данных на всём разделе... а про журнал — я уже сказал, если ты __специально__ при создании ФС не включал журналирование данных, то журналируются только метаданные... и при затирании раздела затирается и журнал, само собой... если  конечно ты, опять же, специально не поместил его на отдельный раздел — тогда просто затри раздел и с журналом...

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!

Comment: перед удалением также стоит посмотреть не открыт ли файл какойто программой и сколько на него хардлинков.

Comment: Спасибо за совет !!!